# An algorithm to draw graphs without checking all pairs of vertices?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, graph-drawing

Graph drawing algorithms, such as those described [here](http://cs.brown.edu/%7Ert/gdhandbook/chapters/force-directed.pdf), check all the vertices two-by-two and apply additional forces if two vertices are connected by an edge. If we have a very large graph, checking all pairs of vertices would be costly. Is there any graph drawing algorithm that draws a large graph using only existing edges, not by verifying all possible pairs?

**EDIT**
By drawing algorithm, I meant an algorithm that assigns a 2D or 3D position to each vertex such that rendering spheres or circles (or any other shape) as vertices at their assigned positions lead to a plausible visual representation of the whole graph.

Comment: does the graph have to be planar?

Comment: The problem with your question is in very unclear requirements on the drawing algorithm - *"plausible visual representation"* is not a clear objective criteria. I can easily create a very simple drawing algorithm for you, that will fulfill the condition but it will create ugly graphs. Who will decide what is ugly and what is not?

Comment: I had been thinking there must be an algorithm out there in the literature that satisfies mentioned conditions.

Comment: Which conditions? You have specified no clear conditions. Go back and read my previous comment again.

Comment: Conditions on the way the algorithm performs the drawing. I'm looking for a previously proposed algorithm that doesn't have to perform 2-by-2 computation on all vertices in the graph.

Comment: OK, then just assign coordinates [0, 0] to each vertex. That's a drawing algorithm that goes with your conditions.

Comment: See the link in the answer for description. This explains what I wanted. I'm sorry if I couldn't convey properly the idea in my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [Spring-Electrical Embedding](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/GraphDrawingIntroduction.html#194525651)
It is in O(nlog n).

Comment: Thanks. That's what I had been thinking as a solution: confining the attractive force to nearby vertices. I think it adds the overhead of *knowing* neighbors but it's not something that cannot be solved.

Comment: Peng, what is `n`? You should always say what is `n` if you put expression like that. Right @Farzad?

Comment: @Tomas, n is the number of nodes in the graph. This is the common notation from graph theory. :-)

Comment: Well, then it's clearly false, because number of edges can be up to n(n-1)/2. How do you want to draw `O(n^2)` edges in `O(n log n)` time?

Comment: And by the way, answers like this are discouraged, because they don't contain anything besides the link - which might stop working.

Comment: @Tomas what you're referring to is the worst case that doesn't happen for real-world large graphs. Have a look at [SNAP large graph dataset](http://snap.stanford.edu/data/). These large graphs are sparse, they may have millions of vertices but don't have hundreds of billions of edges. Plus this post has the answer I was looking for. A useful link is better than a long useless answer or no answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have sparse matrix you can consider about creating graph as list of neighbours or simplier like pair of vertices (e.g. (1, 3) and 1 and 3 are the numbers of vertices).

Comment: Having the list of edges is a representation and storing format not a graph drawing format. I edit the question and add this.